# UPI Payments not working in razorpay Android Integration

Tags: android, razorpay, upi

I am using the latest `razorpay` sdk for my android app. The integration part was successful. However, I am facing few problems in the transaction while testing in Test Mode.

`UPI` payments were not working but receiving `order id, razor pay id, signature` in `onPaymentSuccess()` callback.

Answer (score 1):

What I can understand is you tried paying through UPI with test keys.

U didn't get any payment request on your PSP app but u received the order id, Razorpay id, and signature. (Stating that the payment was successful)

This is happening because you are using test mode.
All UPI payments are by default marked as success in test mode

For UPI use success@razoroay to test successful transactions. And failure@razorpay to test failed transactions in Test mode.

Comment: Thanks bro saved my life keep it up.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me after submitting the KYC details on the razorpay dashboard. Unless you see payment methods tab on the dashboard, some payment methods would not be available.